# How to reassemble this Fortress combo lock?

Tags: lock

This rarely used lock (in perfect condition) came apart on me today when I put in the combination and pulled up on the shank (with usual force).

The shank is now stuck in this open position.  It does not go up or down and does not rotate. I tried putting in the combination and tried 0-0-0-0 and neither had any effect.

Is there a way to reassemble the lock so it works?

[image: (See photo.)]

Comment: Maybe, but would you trust it to lock something valuable now?

Comment: @SolarMike  I was hoping someone here would tell me about that in their answer.  (It only pulled up like that when I entered the combination.)

Comment: Padlocks tend to be made with the idea that disassembly is not possible… otherwise people would be able to break into them more easily. I doubt it's worth the effort. If a retaining circlip has failed inside, then pulling the shaft that far out will have let the tumblers… tumble.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about home improvement within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: @FreeMan When I searched DIY for questions on padlocks, I found many listings. So I thought it was an acceptable topic for this forum.